# How to give multiple condition in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Have to implement scenario where both && and || should work in one expression like below

```
ng-class = "{'class_name' : condition1 || condition2 || (condition3 && condition4)}"
```

Its possible if yes then how?

Comment: doesn't it work like you wrote?

Comment: That should work fine but it's probably easier to test/maintain if you create a new function in the controller that combines all of your logic. Something like model.isClassNameOn = function() { return model.condition1 || model.condition2 || (model.condition3 && model.condition4); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dan Thank you so much for your comment.

as question This not working directly but using the function works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you wrote it, if it doesn't make sure you have the right starting and closing of brackets and parenthesis. It would be helpful if you post your code here. If you want to understand more using ng-class, you can go through the following well-written article.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass